# Primefaces datatable dynamic update

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to update the datatable columns (particular columns) dynamically as the data changes in the server it has to reflect in UI through ajax call. How can I achieve this with primeface.

Comment: How about using p:poll? Check this : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use polling mechanism provided by primefaces using [**p:poll**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) tag.

From Primefaces Documentation:

> Poll is an ajax component that has the ability to send periodical ajax
>   requests and execute listeners on JSF backing beans

```
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:dataTable id="tab" ...>
      //cols
    </p:dataTable>  

    <p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="tab" />  
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what about the performance?if there is huge data for each interval if we get whole data from data base when there is a change in couple of columns.?