# Load parts of the data lazily in prime faces data-table

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

**Sometimes** we bring IDs (or some key values) using some DB Query, and grab other data (which is time-consuming for instance) using different DB Query or even from completely different data source.

**In standard** `HTML/JQuery` app, we could get the IDs and draw them on the form in one Request/Response cycle, then for each particular row, we could send separate Ajax requests for each row and then draw the result in the data-tabble.

**My Question is**, How to achieve such function in typical `Primefaces` App?

**EDIT**

I want to have similar behaviour like this one:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml
But instead of expansion, I want the data that display in the expansion to be displayed lazily on columns on the main data table.

Comment: Loading id's and then looping over them and doing a separate ajax call for each id sounds like bad practice. PrimeFaces does not support that. If you have expensive queries and you still want to show that in a datatable on many rows, you most likely have design issue. Either in the database/model or ui. Since both result in bad uix

Comment: I'm confused by your example in the for a "standard HTML/JQuery app". So you get the IDs/rows, draw them, and then for each row you get more data and draw it? What would these even look like? First a mostly empty table is drawn, and then the table fields get gradually populated?

Comment: Okay, the IDs is not DB Ids, it is user ID (and other related columns) and this what most the end-user is concerning about. Besides, If I run one query to get all data at once, it took to much time besides (more than a minute), the data might came from two data sources. and this actually a model already used currently.

Comment: @DavidS: yes. I've seen it happen on several websites. Very annoying, distracting etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax poll to update data table for once after update data table model cancel poll request
[Primefaces datatable dynamic update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196132/primefaces-datatable-dynamic-update)

Comment: I am surprised this isan answer to the question. How and what are you updating it theb and how is that any quicker than directly showing all...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lazy Datatable with pagination if you are concerned with overloaded datables. Example usage can be found on primefaces showcase [Primefaces Datatable (Lazy)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml)

Comment: I want lazy load for Columns (Not rows)

Comment: did you check dynamic columns it might be helpful in that case